# Why print an object name is name of prototype.constructor rather than the name of constructor in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function Foo () {
    console.log('Foo');
}

Foo.prototype.constructor = function Boo () {
    console.log('Boo');
}

console.log(new Foo());
```

result in nodejs@v7.3.0

```
Foo
Boo {}
```

result in chrome@57.0.2987.110

```
Foo
Foo {}
```

I think the chrome look more reasonable, Because of its reaction is the name of the constructor. Which one is right?

Comment: Console output is non-standard. There isn't a "correct" output.

Comment: And in Firefox it's `Object {}`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why print an object name is name of prototype.constructor rather than the name of constructor in nodejs?

Because the nodejs console is implemented in the JS environment, and can only query `val.constructor.name`. In contrast, Chrome devtools are a *debugger*, and its console can access internal details of the instance.

> Which one is right?

Both and neither. There is no standard console output format. Each implementation tries to be as useful as possible.